# extract columns containing a specific string in the header

Tags: awk

I have a tab delimited file, where I want to scan the header (first line) for columns that contain a key word. Then, I want to print only those columns from the rest of the file.

From this example file:

```
sample  AAA BBB sample_CCC  DDD EEE sample_FFF
000 aaa bbb ccc ddd eee fff
```

I am looking to get something like this:

```
sample  sample_CCC  sample_FFF
000 ccc fff
```

I have tried:

```
awk -F"\t" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if ($i ~ /sample/){print $i}}}' filename > outputfile
```

however, this only pulls out columns with that exact string (sample), not columns that contain it (sample_CCC, sample_FFF).

Is there a way to alter this code so that it will pull columns that do not match the string exactly, but contain the string?

Comment: So you want to scan the header (first line) for columns that contain a key word; you then want to print only those columns from the rest of the file?

Comment: yes that's exactly what I'm trying to do

Comment: Feel free to steal my words into the question, if you find them helpful!

Answer (score 2):

perl allows a nice concise solution:

```
perl -ale '
    @cols = grep {$F[$_] =~ /sample/} 0..$#F if $. == 1;
    print "@F[@cols]";
' file
```

Comment: Conciseness means brevity with clarity. YMMV with the clarity part of that :-)

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this?

```
NR==1   {
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
                if ($i ~ /sample/) {
                        head[i]= $i
                        printf "%s\t", $i
                }
        }
        printf "\n"
}

NR>1    {
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
                if (head[i]) {
                        printf "%s\t", $i
                }
        }
        printf "\n"
}
```

A somewhat naïve approach, but it does the job for small files.

Comment: Use `head[i]=1` (less memory) instead. The match should be against an string (not a regex), use `($i ~ "sample")`.

Comment: you should be able to use `for i in head printf "%s\t,$i`  instead of looping all columns.

Comment: I tried the 'for i in head' but it put them in hash order instead of the order that the columns appear in the file - maybe that's awk-implementation-specific?

Comment: The output loop will result in a spurious trailing separator I think? either you need a special case for `i==NF`, or perhaps assemble a new record like `j=0; for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if(i in head) $++j = $i}` then a simple `print`

Comment: I agree that there's an extra tab at the end of the line, but there's no guarantee that there's a "sample" text when i==NF, so you probably need a flag to say "tab before next item"?

Comment: @mmusante that was my point - although I believe you can avoid the need for such a flag by dynamically re-assembling the record as I showed (and letting awk's default `print` decide where to put the separators)

Comment: @Isaac can you explain why `"sample"` is preferred over `/sample/` in a `~` regex match? At least according to the GNU Awk user's guide [Using Dynamic Regexps](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Computed-Regexps.html#Computed-Regexps) that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: @steeldriver Yes, you are correct, it doesn't matter. What lies on the right side of the `~` is treated as a regex even if generated from a string.

Comment: No, `-F "\t"` is fine: awk understands that the 2 character string `\t` represents a tab.

Comment: @Isaac no, it does matter and `"sample"` is a worse choice than `/sample/`

Comment: @steeldriver actually `/sample/` is preferred over `"sample"` because you're doing a regexp comparison with `~` and `/.../` are the regexp literal delimiters. When you use `"..."` those are string delimiters and so awk has to first convert that string to a regexp and THEN use it as that regexp. So there's a small efficiency hit and the code is misleading, but more importantly it means that any escapes have to be doubled up if you use `"..."` as they're going to be parsed/consumed twice. Try `echo '\' | awk '$0 ~ /\\/'` vs `echo '\' | awk '$0 ~ "\\"'` (then keep adding escapes to the latter!).

Comment: Yes Ed. It does matter as you explain. But both are treated as regexps, not as an string comparison as done in index. I was thinking in shell mode, where quoting makes the string explicit, not in awk mode in my first comment. @EdMorton

Comment: @glennjackman the OP said `this only pulls out columns with that exact string (sample), not columns that contain it (sample_CCC, sample_FFF).` which I took to mean that the version of awk did not in fact understand the tab - setting it directly in the awk script (as Ed Morton did below) is probably a more portable approach

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '
    BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
    NR==1 {
        for (inFldNr=1; inFldNr<=NF; inFldNr++) {
            if ($inFldNr ~ /sample/) {
                out2inFldNr[++numOutFlds] = inFldNr
            }
        }
    }
    {
        for (outFldNr=1; outFldNr<=numOutFlds; outFldNr++) {
            inFldNr = out2inFldNr[outFldNr]
            printf "%s%s", $inFldNr, (outFldNr<numOutFlds ? OFS : ORS)
        }
    }
' file
sample  sample_CCC      sample_FFF
000     ccc     fff
```